# Arabic letters not joining

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs5, arabic

[image]

Writing Arabic in InDesign cs5 has not been a problem ever before, but today it started to annoy me, as I didn't do anything different than I usually do and didn't touch any settings, etc. Kerning is as it was before and has always been on 'zero'.

Even the letters that are joined (blue highlighted) - the attached picture are separating from one another!

I have InDesign CS5 for PC. It is not a Middle Eastern version.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a shot in the dark, as I don't have the font you used, but have you checked your composer settings? You should use *World-Ready Composer* when typesetting in Middle Eastern / Eastern languages, or else the text will just be rendered as individual characters, and not a ligature.

[image]

You can access this option by clicking on the fly-out menu of `Paragraph` panel and selecting one of the two `World-Ready` options (`Single-line` or `Paragraph`).

[image: InDesign Composer options]

Oh and, just a friendly advice: don't use pirated webfonts in DTP apps. They can cause more trouble than not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed your instructions, but sadly I can ONLY see: 'Adobe Paragraph composer' and 'Adobe Single-line composer'. As already mentioned, i didn't have this problem before in all my years working with in InDesign and nor have i fiddled with any settings, and it randomly started playing up..